# How do you 'intercept' all HTTP requests in an EmberJs app?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, ember.js, interceptor

I would like to be able to capture all HTTP requests and responses, and modify them, before they get to the rest of an EmberJs app. I would like to do this globally - across the entire app. I have not been able to find this digging through [the API](http://emberjs.com/api/). How can this be done?

(Modification is to perform some conditional logic based in certain headers, or to add or modify certain headers).

---

In AngularJS, you can accomplish this using something like this:

```
App.factory('AppHttpInterceptor', function($q) {
    return {
        request: function(req) {
            //modify request
            return req;
        },
        response: function(res) {
            // modify response
            return res || $q.when(res);
        }
    };
});

App.config(function ($httpProvider) {
  $httpProvider.interceptors.push('AppHttpInterceptor');
});
```

Comment: nice question.  Thought for a moment it was tagged with angularjs by mistake.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, it's important to note that Angular and Ember are not built to serve the same purpose.  They are both javascript frameworks, and that's about where the similarities end. Another big factor in the difference of async requests in the two framework is Angular's integration of promises into it's async services. Ember async services are not promise based, and therefore response interceptors are not possible (see my note below).

AngularJS provides `$httpProvider` as a configurable singleton that returns a configured instance of `$http` *as a promise object*.  Angular focuses on services rather than methods (although it does have a *few* methods it gives you), and that's what sets Angular apart from other frameworks like Ember, which give you a structure to build services, but doesn't provide services in it's core.

Instead, with Ember, you'd have to build a service and service provider concept yourself. You could take something like [cerebris/ember-rest](https://github.com/cerebris/ember-rest), and extend it in such a way as to use properties you describe. This library provides an `Ember.resource` method, which you could use prototype to extend from there:

```
Ember.ResourceAdapter.extend({
    _prepareResourceRequest: function(params) {
      params.beforeSend = function (xhr, settings) {
       //set your xhr interceptors here
      }
    }
  });
```

#### Edit: Clarification on use of `$ajax` in ember and `$http` in Angular (promises vs callbacks)

The biggest difference on how angular makes response interceptors possible, is that async requests in angular are `promises`, whereas `$ajax` calls are not. Without getting too much into the weeds, you can assign variables to each step of a promise, making it available for mutation/handling along every step of the way, whereas with `$ajax`, you can only perform operations when the data has completely returned.  With Promises, assign variables to represent states at any point during the lifecycle of the promise, and using that reference, you can mutate the promise as needed, at any point in time prior to the event of the promise fully resolving.

Thus why it's possible to do request interceptors with `$ajaxPrefilter` but there is **no good way to do response interceptors**, using the abstract configuration approach with `$ajax`.  To truly do in Ember what AngularJS does with `$http`, you need to create a promise based async request/response service, as opposed to utilizing non-promise based xhr requests such as `$ajax`.

jQuery does provide an `$ajaxSetup()` method, which you might be able to set a `dataFilter` property to and define a handler function, however this is not recommended.  With angular, the `$httpProvider` can be configured by module, and through de-coupling and Separation of Concerns, this can become truly powerful, allowing you to encapsulate and cascade http interceptor configurations with a lot of control. Making the same changes to your ajax settings will register themselves on the global jquery namespace, and can cause conflicts if you need to grow your app.

One video I found particularly englightening on this subject was from ng-conf 2014: [Christion Lilley: Going Postal with Angular Promises](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XcRdO5QVlqE)

#### Edit 2: addressing Ember.RSVP

While `Ember.RSVP` is indeed a promise class useable in the framework, it does not have any methods available to perform resource requests.  This means you have to manually assign an http request instance to an instance of RSVP.deferred such that it resolves your http request before returning the promise.

This allows you to do interceptors on both sides of each individual request, but does not provide a solution for configuring interceptors for all requests.  You'd have to create another function or service for that, and extend RSVP with this function.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I take it that that implies that Ember does not provide a means to do this on its own. Since Ember (presently) uses jQuery to handle all its AJAX requests, I thought why not look into that, and it turns out that [$.ajaxPrefilter](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajaxprefilter/) provides a means to do intercept all HTTP requests. Have not found a function that intercepts responses though...

Comment: that's right. Ember itself doesn't do this on it's own. I was going to suggest the bit you found with jQuery, but it's not quite the same. angularjs uses promises, which enable response interceptors to happen, whereas regular old `$ajax` is a callback based service, and can only filter data in a callback.  I edited my answer to explain the difference.

Comment: +1 and check to you. Thank you very much for the thorough explanation - I was under the impression that Ember wraps its HTTP requests using [their RSVP promises](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.RSVP.html), but I must be mistaken.

Comment: updated my answer again to address this. TL;DR, RSVP is a promise class, but not an ajax request service. angular combines both, then uses several other OO patterns to allow the configurations described by your question and my answer.